# Detecting if an image can be made BW/Greyscale/Colour

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-classification, cnn

I am attempting to classify images of documents into Black&White, Greyscale and Colour. I originally get these images as colour images and in order to save space I want to change the bit depth where possible without a loss of 'content' from the original image.

I have hand labelled around 3000 documents (I could do more) based on what I though they should be changed to (BW/Greyscale/Remain as colour). Generally speaking I labelled them as the lowest possible bit depth without a loss of 'content'. It was acceptable to lose colour apart from in the case of things such as photographs where the amount of colour in the document was large.

I have tried a number of approaches such as taking the image histograms from the grey scaled and black documents and using them as a feature in a number of machine learning models such as a RandomForestClassifier. Creating an ensemble of classifiers, created a CNN LSTM where there were 3 input images. The colour image, the grey scaled image and the black a white image. I have tried doing some transfer learning in order to try an make up for my relatively small dataset and I have also tried a small conventional CNN, non of which where able to go anywhere above 83%.

The dataset has a rough split of BW = 1700, Greyscale = 800, Colour = 500.

The most confusion is between the BW and Greyscale class. I'm running out of ideas as how to tackle such a task as I have looked online and have never seen someone try and approach such a problem.

I am wondering if there are any particular model architectures anyone has used before or features I could extract from the images to help my classification accuracy.

Comment: Have you considered changing the values of least significant bits to zeros? it may reduce their size.

Comment: @Media I ran PCA on the image histograms and reduced the number of features from 1024 to 7 and retained the same level of accuracy. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Actually there are numerous things that can be applied. Before doing what you have referred, you can do something which can be helpful. If your images are uint8, you can set the last bits which are least significant to zero. Then apply PCA.

Comment: Are your documents clean? If not, this could introduce noise. For example, a BW document that shows some background (from outside of the document) on the edges might introduce color as noise. Many people might point out that an end-to-end network should be able to resolve this for you, but I would still argue that being aware of the introduced noise is part of knowing the problem when looking for a solution.

Comment: If we focus on the BW vs Grayscale part of the problem, I think it's obvious that due to the noise introduced by the scan, you'll end up with grayscale documents in either case. Then it becomes a case of what nuances of gray you want to perserve. Depending on your intentions, your solution might be as simple as reducing the colour space (from your comment on PCA seems that 3-bit gray is good enough). A more careful manipulation could be several [adaptive thresholding](https://www.docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) passes to get your grayscale nuances.